# Display web page fullscreen on Iphone browser

Tags: iphone, resolution

I have a page on my website that has to be displayed only on iPhone. I kept the resolution of the background image page 960X640 according to iPhone 4. But on opening on iPhone, the page donot covered the whole screen but left some space around it.

I thought that it must be a resolution issue and searched the web but didn't found anything.

[Here is the link to my website page](http://www.chargebar.com.au/iphone-app.)

please tell me how can this be displayed in  the whole screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the body margin of you webpage to 0px. `<body style="margin: 0">...</body>`